# Backbone event callback bind

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to bind a user defined callback as Backbone's click event.

```js
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    
    events: {
      'click': 'testClick'
    },
    
    tagName: "li",
    
    attributes: {
      class: "item"
    },
    
    initialize: function() {
      
        this.render();
      
    },
    
    testClick: function(){      
      
    },
    
    render: function() {
      
      $("#container").append(this.$el.html("Click Me!!"));
      
    }
    
  });

function Item() {  
  
  var _view = View.extend({
    
    testClick: this.testClick.bind(this)
    
  });
  
  this.view = new _view();
  
}

Item.prototype = {
  
  testClick: function() {
    
    alert("testClick from prototype called!");
    
  }
  
};


var myItem = new Item();

myItem.testClick = function() {
  alert("testClick from instance called!");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Clicking on "Click me", it alerts "testClick from prototype called!"

I am not sure why the alert from the instance is not getting called. What am I doing wrong here? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the following line:

```
testClick: this.testClick.bind(this)
```

*detaches* the `testClick` function member of the `Item` instance. You are essentially reusing a function and there is no linkage between the 2 methods.

Consider this example:

```
var obj = {
   foo: function() {
      console.log('I was foo!');
   }
}

var detachedFoo = obj.foo;
obj.foo = function() {
   console.log('The new foo!');
}

obj.foo === detachedFoo // false
obj.foo() // logs 'The new foo!'
deatchedFoo(); // logs 'I was foo!'
```

If you use the following syntax the `alert` will show "testClick from instance called!".

```
testClick: () => {
   this.testClick();
}
```

This is because the above code calls the current `.testClick` method of the Item instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick turn around!! even if we change testClick: this.testClick.bind(this) to testClick: this.testClick, it is not working.

http://jsbin.com/fusupojuno/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @Aneesh You are welcome! There is no difference between those code snippets, it's not about `.bind`. See the example again. It uses an arrow function for remembering the `this` value. `this` refers to the Item's instance and when the method is called it's the current member of the instance not a detached function. The main point is this.